# Import from MySql dump to hive

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I am facing a problem while importing MySql dump into Hive.

I used `sqoop` connector to import data from `MySql` to `Hive` successfully. However, there are more data dumps to import to Hive. Restoring the database first is not feasible. Since the dump size is of 300G, hence takes 3 days to restore. Also, I can't restore more than two files on MySql because of disk space issue.

As a result, I am looking to import data, which is in MySql dump, directly into hive without restoring into MySql.

There is one more problem with the MySql dump is that there are multiple insert statements (around 1 billion). So will it creates multiple files for each insert? In that case, how to merge them?

Comment: provide more details like the data format in

Comment: I have a mysql data dump which I want to import directly into hive ( HDFS underlying it) without restoring it to the MySql.

Comment: Hi @GauravKumar, If you succeeded in doing this, can you please share the process you followed for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "load" command provided by Hive to load data present in the your local directory.

Example: This will load the data present in the file fileName.csv into your hive table tableName.

```
load data local inpath '/tmp/fileName.csv' overwrite into table tableName;
```

In case your data is present in the HDFS.Use the same load command without local option.

Example:Here /tmp/DataDirectory is a HDFS directory and all the files present in that directory will be loaded into Hive.

```
load data inpath '/tmp/DataDirectory/*' overwrite into table tableName;
```

Caution: As Hive is schema on read make sure to take care of your line delimiter and field delimiter are same in both the file and the Hive table you are loading into.